# 2 files with same name in eclipse

Tags: database, eclipse

I have 2 source folders in my project:

`src/main/resources/sql/oracle`

`src/main/resources/sql/sqlserver`

They both have a file called `mh1.sql`.

The project I'm working on used to support only oracle database, so it just use `ClassPathResource("mh1.sql")` to load the sql file directly, now I need to support different kinds of database, and switch to the correct sql file according to the database type we're using. So, is there any good way to go? without any big impact on the old project. any rough ideas?

BTW, I find that after compilation, I can only find one `mh1.sql` under `bin` folder, I'm a new guy in using Eclipse, and I'm curious to know if it's possible to output these 2 folder `oracle` and `sqlserver` to the `bin` folder and each contains its own `mh1.sql` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your second question without knowing your exact Eclipse project settings it's of course close to impossible to tell why you're not seeing the `oracle` and `sqlserver` subfolders in your `bin` folder. However, it should be obvious that this being fixed is a prerequisite for your first problem.

Have a look at the [ClassPathResource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html) docs, they tell you that you can/should provide a *path* to your resource rather than just the name. Hence, you can use `ClassPathResource("sql/oracle/mh1.sql")`.

Having said all that you might also just dump the two files in `src/main/resources/sql/` (omitting the subfolders) and give them unique names: `ora-mh1.sql` and `mssql-mh1.sql`.